# Display variables in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, php-5.3, symfony-2.1

I have a bizzare situation. So I have the following situation:

```
{% for order in aFilteredOrdersBySupplier %}
  {% set article_id = order.ref_article %}
  {{  dump(form_logistique[article_id].article_id) }}
  {{  dump(article_id) }}
  {{  dump(1903) }}
{% endfor %}
```

For this code : `{{  dump(article_id) }} {{  dump(1903) }}` I get in template :

```
int 1903 int 1903
```

There are identique numbers. Soo, if I tried :

```
{{  dump(form_logistique[article_id].1903) }}
```

Work fine, but If I write :

```
{{  dump(form_logistique[article_id].article_id) }}
```

I get null. 
The form_logistique are the content :

```
array (size=2)
1903 => 
object(Form)[58]
  private 'a_field' => 
    array (size=2)
      1903 => 
        object(Text)[59]
          ...
      'availability' => 
        object(Checkbox)[60]
          ...
1904 => 
object(Form)[61]
  private 'a_field' => 
    array (size=2)
      1904 => 
        object(Text)[62]
          ...
      'availability' => 
        object(Checkbox)[63]
          ...
```

I don't understand where is the problem. I can't explain this situation. Please help me! Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `form_logistique[article_id]` will return an object, `form_logistique[article_id].article_id` will search for a member called `article_id` (literally) and not for his value.

If you want to access that value, try with [attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

```
attribute(form_logistique[article_id], article_id)
```